# Eclipse RCP Application - Application launches with a tiny window before it automatically maximize to window size

Tags: java, linux, eclipse-rcp

While I launch my application in the linux environment I get a tiny window and then it automatically maximizes to the window size.

I do not know why the application launches in a tiny window size at the start.

```
public void postWindowOpen()
{

    IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
        .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    IViewPart cView = activePage
        .findView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);
    if (cView != null)
    {
        activePage.hideView(cView);
    }
    getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getShell().setMaximized(true);
}

public void postWindowCreate()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.postWindowCreate();

    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell();
    if(null != shell && !shell.isDisposed())
    {
        shell.setMaximized(true);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid getting this issue

Comment: Are you calling `getWindowConfigurer().setInitialSize(xxx)` somewhere (probably in `preWindowOpen`)?

Comment: @greg-449 I have n't set getWindowConfigurer().setInitialSize(xxx) anywhere in the code. I get this issue only in the linux environment not in windows.                
                                                                                                                               In the Linux environment I get this issue only while launching using a remote session. Please help